# javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm getting the below error when running Spring Boot app in Intellij:

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/adi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.29/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext

Answer (score 0):

I would just delete the entire `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext/` directory.

Servlet API should not be a part of the JDK.

This Java version is also ancient, so installing a more recent Java build and using it for your project is probably an even better solution.